# getting the hour from current time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get the 12 hours from the current time.

when i try this:

```
# Set the date and time row
current_time = time.time() # now (in seconds)
half_hour = current_time + 60*30  # now + 30 minutes
one_hour = current_time + 60*60  # now + 60 minutes


for t in [current_time,half_hour,one_hour]:
    if (0 <= datetime.datetime.now().minute <= 29):
        self.getControl(346).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":30%p",time.localtime(t)).lstrip("%p"))
    else:
        self.getControl(346).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":30%p",time.localtime(t)).lstrip("0"))
```

it will not get the hour from the current time to add the hours, as because i'm using `time.strftime("%I"`

I want to get the hours from the current time to get the hours and add the hours.

The return output would be:

```
7
```

I want to get the hours from the current time so i could then add the hours forward from the current time.

Can you show me of example how I can get the hours from current time without the `20150511070000`?

Comment: Where is **your attempt**, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, please see the update

Comment: I think the OP wants the hour in 12 hour format. If its 1:30 pm, he wants the hour to be `1` not `13`

Comment: @letsc do you know how i can get the hour to be like `1` or whatever it is from the current time using 12 hour?

Comment: look at the accepted answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554589/24-hour-time-conversion-to-12-hour-clock-problemsetquestion-on-python

Comment: @letsc cant you post the code that will work mine?

Comment: All you want is `13:30` to show up as `1:30`?

Comment: Yes but I only want to get the hours so i can add it in the label, example: `self.getControl(346).setLabel(gethours + onehour + ":30%p",time.localtime(t)).lstrip("%p")`

Comment: "I want to get the 12 hours from the current time" is the key part of the question, IMO. The other parts of this question are a symptom of a weird attempt at getting the time 12 hours from now, which is the real issue.

Comment: @Ezra i have tried with this `self.getControl(346).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + str(self.half_hours) + ":30%p",time.localtime(t)).lstrip("%p"))`, it will return to something is like `80:30PM` which it should be `8:30PM`. any idea?

Comment: My advice is to use the `datetime` library instead of `time`. Say `t = datetime.datetime.now()` for current time, `d = datetime.timedelta(hours=12)` for a difference of 12 hours. Say `t + d`, and parse the time you want out of that. I'd give you a proper answer, but this question is "put on hold", so you'll "fix" and get it re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Get the Shifted Time

Dealing with times is tricky, so I encourage you to use library calls to do the work for you wherever possible. Time-math gets really messy, really fast.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

original_time = datetime.now() # datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 12, 32, 46, 246004)
print(original_time) # 2015-05-11 12:32:46.246004

offset = timedelta(hours=12) # datetime.timedelta(0, 43200)
shifted_time = original_time + offset # datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12, 0, 32, 46, 246004)
print(shifted_time) # 2015-05-12 00:32:46.246004
```

### Then Read What You Need

With the time shifted, you can easily read any part of the time, on either the original time, or the new time:

```
original_time # datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 12, 32, 46, 246004)
original_time.hour # 12
original_time.year # 2015
original_time.month # 5
original_time.day # 11
original_time.hour # 12
original_time.minute # 32
original_time.second # 46
```

Looking at [the Datetime Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) shows you that the ranges for the values are as follows:

```
MINYEAR <= year <= MAXYEAR
1 <= month <= 12
1 <= day <= number of days in the given month and year
0 <= hour < 24
0 <= minute < 60
0 <= second < 60
```

### Then Format and Print

If you need another behaviour for printing, use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), as you have been.

```
datetime.strftime(original_time, "%I") # '12'
datetime.strftime(original_time, "%I:30%p") # '12:30PM'
datetime.strftime(shifted_time, "%I:30%p") # '12:30AM'
datetime.strftime(shifted_time, "%Y %H %M %S") # '2015 00 32 46'
datetime.strftime(original_time, "%Y %H %M %S") # '2015 12 32 46'
```

### Key Points

#### Time Math

Be aware of are `timedelta` which allows you to easily perform math on times and dates. Operations are as simple as `t1 = t2 + t3` and `t1 = t2 - t3` to add or subtract times.

#### Formatting

Use `strftime` to output your `datetime` in the desired format.