# How to convert 24 hour format to 12 hour format in python datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime

how can I convert 24 hour format to 12 hour format while using now() function.

```
from datetime import *

current_time = datetime.now()

print(current_time)
```

Any other ways to do this than  strftime().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855111/how-can-i-convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time)

Comment: is there any other way of doing it than strftime().

Comment: You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554589/24-hour-time-conversion-to-12-hour-clock-problemsetquestion-on-python) whose answer proposes an implementation of what you want to do.

Comment: "is there any other way of doing it than strftime()"—we can't help you find a good solution if you reject good answers without explaining why.

Comment: Note that `current_time` is a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), not a string. datetime objects do not have a *format* like 12h or 24h clock. Only a string that represents date & time has that - so you *have* to use `strftime` if you want to have the one or the other format.

Comment: Please also note [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use strftime function

```
from datetime import *
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")
print(current_time)
```

Comment: See the question I linked in the comments section - please avoid suggesting `from ... import *` (although that appears in the OP's example). Here you just need `from datetime import datetime`.